# Java code to send email only works for one email id?

Tags: java, email

The below code in java is used by me to send email to folks in my team However it only works if  `public static String to = "marsh@gmail.com";` but it would not work if i have `public static String to = "marsh@gmail.com, mark@gmail.com";` not sure what am i missing can someone help me to send emails to multiple id at the same time ? currently the code can only send to one person at a time ?

```
public static String to = "marsh@gmail.com, mark@gmail.com";
public static String from= "SANDBOX";
public static String host = "localhost"; 

public  static void send_production_email(String reportDate){

    System.out.println("Preparing to Send Email to Admin's...");

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

       message.setSubject(" Production Database Backed up Successfully");

       message.setContent("<h4> Production Database Backup Completed on" +reportDate+" </h4><br>"   
            + "<h4>Please do not respond to this email as this is an auto generated email</h4></br>"
            +"<h4>Thank You!</h4></br>" );
       Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }
      catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding multiple recipients?

Comment: Just have: String[] to = { "marsh@gmail.com", "mark@gmail.com" }; and call message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[0])); message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[1]));

Comment: <blink><strong><large>DO YOU REALLY WANT ALL OF THE MESSAGE TO BE IN h4 TAGS?</large></strong></blink>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `message.addRecipient()` for each email address or `addRecipients()` with an array of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to specify more than one recipient; in short, you must use one "string" per "address", just for you to understand, try modifying temporarily your code for something like this:

```
// cahnge temporary:
public static String to = "marsh@gmail.com";
public static String to2 = "mark@gmail.com";
```

and also:

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        new InternetAddress[] {new InternetAddress(to), new InternetAddress(to2)});
```